# Specify language version for Roslyn SyntaxFactory

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am currently building a C# source generator with Roslyn in a `netstandard2.0` library. In the `.csproj`, I have referenced the following Roslyn packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The source generator uses Roslyn's `SyntaxFactory` to create additional code. It then uses `context.Compilation.AddSyntaxTrees()` to add the generated code to the compilation (`context` is the `GeneratorExecutionContext` passed to the generator's `Execute` method).

The problem is that I get the following exception upon calling `AddSyntaxTrees()`:

> **System.ArgumentException:** Inconsistent language versions. Parameter name: syntaxTrees

I understand the reason for the exception. The syntax trees created by the `SyntaxFactory` have their language versions set to `CSharp10`. But the language version of the compilation context is set to `CSharp8`.

Is there a way to tell the `SyntaxFactory` the language version it should produce?

I understand that I could also use version 3.7 of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers` (according to  [this table](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/NuGet-packages.md)). But would this not also prevent me from using the latest Roslyn features (not sure what that might be, though). Furthermore, how can I be sure that the target libraries that use the source generator will ever only be compiled with the same language version? Or do I need different versions for the source generator for different language versions? Also - might this differ in different IDEs?

Comment: I worry a bit about "It then uses context.Compilation.AddSyntaxTrees() to add the generated code to the compilation (context is the GeneratorExecutionContext passed to the generator's Execute method)." since there's some performance implications there that could be problematic. Are the trees you're creating depending on the contents of the original compilation going in? And are you needing to do secondary binding that isn't possible the first time around?

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for looking out for additional problems. I need the semantic model of the compilation to generate the code. And I just realized that calling `AddSyntaxTrees` does not actually add the code to the compiled result. Switching to `context.AddSource` with code retrieved from `compilationUnit.ToFullString()` works, however. Is this how it is supposed to do or is there a smarter way? It feels like an unnecessary complication (formatting the syntax tree as a string just so the compiler can re-parse it back).

Comment: Yeah, we require you to give us text rather than a tree directly; the reason is somewhat obscure: it's possible to produce syntax trees that don't represent actual parseable code; for example you could nest binary expressions in a way without parenthesis that violates how the parser would actually apply operator precedence. (You can figure out no end of these issues.) Rather than trying to figure out how the compiler should deal with all of those crazy cases, we decided the input is text, so we're always reparsing it into the more standard form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a SyntaxTree you can set its language version with the ParseOptions argument.

```
var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.CSharp8);
var syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.SyntaxTree(root, options);
```

[SyntaxFactory.SyntaxTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory.syntaxtree?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.0.1#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_SyntaxFactory_SyntaxTree_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxNode_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_ParseOptions_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_)

Comment: Oh, it's really that simple. Thanks a lot. I was relying on the `SyntaxTree` property of the `CompilationUnitSyntax`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to spesify tha LanguageVersion in a syntax tree that you create with code, you can use the following:

```
var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.CSharp10);
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code, options);
```